# Update checkbox value being checked - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a checkbox:

```
 <CheckBox 
   checked={this.state.preference} 
   onPress={() => this.setState({
     preference: !this.state.preference
   })}
 />
```

Initially, I want the checkbox to be checked based on the data i'm fetching.
I have a preference field whose value is 0 , so I've put :

```
{
  this.props.data.profile && this.props.data.profile.preference== 0 ? 
    this.state.preference = false : this.state.preference= true
}
```

But now onPress, the this.state.preferences does not change, because it still gets the profile.preference value.

How do I fix this ?
Initially the checkbox is checked based on the `this.props.data.profile.preference`, and then onPress I can change that ?

```
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      showForm: 0,
      active: true,  
      emailPreference: true,

  };
```

so right before the checkbox I have the :
 if this.props.data.profile && this.props.data.profile.preference == 0, then make emailPreference false, else emailPreference is true.

And then checked is added based on the emailPreference.
But once this gets the value, even if onPress I change the state from true to false adn vice-versa. it doesn't get updated.

Comment: Post the code of the containing class. I can't tell where you're setting state from `this.props.data.profile`...

Comment: Thank you.This.props.data.profile is passed through my controller that has the fetched data.
So on my screen, if I were to print out: this.props.data.profile.preference , I would have 0.
If the value is 0, I want the checkbox to be checked.
I will add the state.

Comment: Ah, then I believe the problem is you are not using `setState()` to set state.

Answer (score 0):

You should always change the state using setState({ preference: "hello }), never by directly changing this.state. The ternary in your second code snippet is also in the wrong order, and you should use a colon instead of an = inside objects. Overall, I think try this:

```
{
  this.setState({
      preference: this.props.data.profile && this.props.data.profile.preference == 0 ? false : true
  })
}
```